# Summing the result of a query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Ok, so I know what this query should give, it should give the sum of the total it is outputting. I am having trouble figuring out how to sum the results. The database i am using is the publishers database

Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT authors.state, qty*price as total
from authors
JOIN titleauthor on titleauthor.au_id = authors.au_id
JOIN titles on titles.title_id = titleauthor.title_id
JOIN sales on sales.title_id = titles.title_id
JOIN stores on stores.stor_id = sales.stor_id
WHERE authors.state LIKE stores.state
```

and Here is the output it gives

```
CA 104.6500
CA 299.8000
CA 299.8500
CA 1000.0000
```

Comment: If you remove the DISTINCT, what result do you get?

Comment: Basically the same thing that I got here, only with duplicates

Comment: It's the "duplicates" that are important; if you add the sales' IDs to the select statement, you will probably find that in most cases, these represent different sales. In other words, the total value of sales for Californian authors is almost certainly significantly larger than the circa $1703 you would get from summing the distinct values above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joins give you duplicates because they include more than one table representing a many-to-many relationship and the filtering is not sufficient to preclude the many-to-many tables from returning more than one row based on the given join conditions.

You could avoid duplicates by introducing a semi-join in the form of an EXISTS predicate and subsequent moving some of the tables there. Here's one possible way of using EXISTS in your situation:

```
SELECT
  stores.state,
  SUM(qty * price)
FROM sales
INNER JOIN stores ON sales.stor_id  = stores.stor_id
INNER JOIN titles ON sales.title_id = stores.title_id
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM authors a
  INNER JOIN titelauthor ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
  WHERE ta.titel_id = titles.title_id
    AND a.state LIKE stores.state
)
GROUP BY
  stores.state
```

The central table is most likely `sales`, it's where the figures come from. Therefore, the query is being built around `sales`. Other tables are joined explicitly (using a JOIN clause) as long as they return only one row for every row of `sales`. Once a table is going to return more than one row, it gets moved to EXISTS.

There's one more thing. While working on this query, I noticed that one join may be redundant (in your query as well as in mine). The table is `titles`. If your foreign keys are in order, you shouldn't need to join to `titles`, as `titleauthor` could be joined directly to `stores` on `title_id`. (Even if you don't have the corresponding foreign keys, you still don't have to include `titles`, as any possible non-existent titles referenced by either `titleauthor` or `sales` would be filtered out either way.)

So the final query might look like this:

```
SELECT
  stores.state,
  SUM(qty * price)
FROM sales
INNER JOIN stores ON sales.stor_id  = stores.stor_id
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM authors a
  INNER JOIN titelauthor ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
  WHERE ta.titel_id = sales.title_id
    AND a.state LIKE stores.state
)
GROUP BY
  stores.state
```

Comment: But wouldn't you need to include titles so that you can access price in the select statement? I forgot to mention that price is from the titles table.

Comment: In that case, yes, `titles` is needed. It's the first option then.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT authors.state, sum(qty*price) as total
from authors
JOIN titleauthor on titleauthor.au_id = authors.au_id
JOIN titles on titles.title_id = titleauthor.title_id
JOIN sales on sales.title_id = titles.title_id
JOIN stores on stores.stor_id = sales.stor_id
WHERE authors.state = stores.state
group by authors.stat
```

Comment: This isn't the value I expected to get. I expected to get around 1704 which is the sum of my query

Comment: Did you also try with `SELECT DISTINCT authors.state ...`?